# Eslint: how to force multiline object literals and arrays to have the same indent?

Tags: javascript, eslint

E.g. these should be allowed:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

{
  a: 1, b: 2, c: 3,
};

[
  1,
  2,
  3,
];
```

These should not be allowed:

```
{ a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

{
  a: 1, b: 2,
  c: 3,
};
```

I added `"object-property-newline": [2, { allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine: true }],`, but it's still allowing the 2 examples. I also tried several `key-spacing` options but it doesn't do what I want. How do I disallow the last 2 examples?

Comment: "allow" is not the same as "require".

Answer (score 0):

The first example is covered by another rule `object-curly-newline`:

```js
/* eslint object-curly-newline: 2 */

let foo = { a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

// Unexpected line break before this closing brace. (object-curly-newline)
```

The second example works on my computer.

You can check it in this [demo](https://eslint.org/demo/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiLyogZXNsaW50IG9iamVjdC1wcm9wZXJ0eS1uZXdsaW5lOiBbMiwgeyBhbGxvd0FsbFByb3BlcnRpZXNPblNhbWVMaW5lOiB0cnVlIH1dICovXG4vKiBlc2xpbnQgb2JqZWN0LWN1cmx5LW5ld2xpbmU6IDIgKi9cblxuXG5sZXQgZm9vID0geyBhOiAxLFxuICBiOiAyLFxuICBjOiAzLFxufTtcblxubGV0IGJhciA9IHtcbiAgYTogMSwgYjogMixcbiAgYzogMyxcbn07XG4iLCJvcHRpb25zIjp7InBhcnNlck9wdGlvbnMiOnsiZWNtYVZlcnNpb24iOjksInNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiJtb2R1bGUiLCJlY21hRmVhdHVyZXMiOnsianN4Ijp0cnVlfX0sInJ1bGVzIjp7Im5vLXVuZGVmIjoyfSwiZW52Ijp7fX19).